# how to open other drive in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04

I was able to open Windows 7 files when I use Ubuntu 12.04. Now when I use 12.10 I am not able to get it working.

When I run the `mount` command I get this:

```
/dev/sda5 on / type ext2 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/ankit/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ankit)
gvfsd-fuse on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

I have 2 more partitions on my computer one has a Windows 7 installation and the second has some data.

How I can got them working as they did in 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

To see a drives contents it needs to be mounted

In a terminal enter the commands

```
    sudo fdisk -l
```

This tells you what drives the system knows about.  If you just want to mount it temporarily see here

http://www.ehow.com/how_4513872_mount-drive-ubuntu-linux.html

If you want the drives to be visible all the time see here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions